# Excel 2016 VBA Problem Run-Time Error 91 - Delete a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

My company is currently upgrading to Office 365 and Excel (64 bit) from Office 2013 (32 bit).  I've been "given the opportunity" to resolve some VBA issues.

I don't have much experience and have spend a couple hours trying to resolve the issue I describe below.  I'm sure this is a simple fix for someone with more knowledge than I.  I know going from Excel 2016 32 bit to Excel 2016 64 bit is now using VBA 7.

There is some VBA that creates a temporary sheet and when it attempts to delete it it is throwing the "Run Time Error 91.  Object Variable or With block variable not set" error.

cleanup:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Cws.Delete  'this is line that fails
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'Remove formula
Range("V3", Cells(Fill_Row, 34)).ClearContents
```

---

### [code issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlLDn.png)

Any idea what I need to change?

Complete code below:

''''
    Sub CreateFile()

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim Ash As Worksheet
Dim Cws As Worksheet
Dim Rcount As Long
Dim Rnum As Long
Dim FilterRange As Range
Dim FieldNum As Integer
Dim mailAddress As String
Dim ccAddress As String
Dim NewWB As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim Fill_Row   As Long
    Dim strDir As String

strDir = Worksheets("Variables").Range("B26")
'Find last row of pivot
Fill_Row = Range("A2")
        ccAddress = Range("B3")
If Range("B2") <> "" Then
If MsgBox(Range("B2") & "  Send anyway?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo cleanup
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Autofill Formula
Range("V2:AH2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("V2", Cells(Fill_Row, 34)), Type:=xlFillDefault

'Set filter sheet, you can also use Sheets("MySheet")
Set Ash = ActiveSheet

'Set filter range and filter column (column with names)
Set FilterRange = Ash.Range("F1:U" & Ash.Rows.Count)
FieldNum = 1    'Filter column = A because the filter range start in column A

'Add a worksheet for the unique list and copy the unique list in A1
Set Cws = Worksheets.Add
FilterRange.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=Cws.Range("A1"), _
        CriteriaRange:="", Unique:=True

'Count of the unique values + the header cell
Rcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cws.Columns(1))

'If there are unique values start the loop
If Rcount >= 2 Then
    For Rnum = 2 To Rcount

        'Look for the mail address in the MailInfo worksheet
        mailAddress = ""
        On Error Resume Next
        mailAddress = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
            VLookup(Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value, _
                      Worksheets("Commission").Range("A5:B" & _
                            Worksheets("Commission").Rows.Count), 2, False)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If mailAddress <> "" Then

            'Filter the FilterRange on the FieldNum column
            FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, _
                                   Criteria1:=Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value

            'Copy the visible data in a new workbook
            With Ash.AutoFilter.Range
                On Error Resume Next
                Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End With

            Set NewWB = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

            rng.Copy
            With NewWB.Sheets(1)
                .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                .Cells(1).Select
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

            'Create a file name
            TempFilePath = strDir & "\"
            TempFileName = "Sales Installed Report for " & Replace(Range("A2"), "/", "-") _
                         & " " & Range("P1")

            If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                'You use Excel 97-2003
                FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
            Else
                'You use Excel 2007-2016
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            End If

            'Save, Mail, Close and Delete the file

            With NewWB
                .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName _
                      & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
                On Error Resume Next

                On Error GoTo 0
                .Close savechanges:=False
            End With

        End If

        'Close AutoFilter
        Ash.AutoFilterMode = False

    Next Rnum
End If



cleanup:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Cws.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'Remove formula
Range("V3", Cells(Fill_Row, 34)).ClearContents

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

''Send email if agent has no sales
'Call No_Sale_Email


''Display pop up window
MsgBox "Report Complete."

End Sub
```

''''

Comment: Can you please share more of the code. Need to see where `Cws` was declared - the error implies that the sheet cannot be found so the issue with code is somewhere above this line

Comment: Sub CreateFile()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Ash As Worksheet
    Dim Cws As Worksheet

Comment: Please update your code in the question and add more. We don't want to have to piece snippits together. Show where the sheet was declared, set, and referenced

Comment: The error means the `Cws` object reference is referring to `Nothing`, i.e. it's "not set". We can't really help you beyond that without seeing where it's declared and how it's assigned. If it's not assigned, then that's why it's blowing up. You need to have `Set Cws = SomeWorksheet` somewhere before you invoke any member against `Cws`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be because you haven't assigned a value to the variable yet

(for example, set cws = Thisworkbook.sheets ("sheetname")) 
Please check the cws variable again

Answer (score 0):

There is an error BEFORE you set cws as the new sheet added. Your Error isn't on deleting a sheet. Your error occurs because you have:

```
On Error GoTo cleanup
```

which takes you to:

```
cleanup:
Cws.Delete
```

Before:

```
 Set Cws = Worksheets.Add
```

Get rid of "On Error...", check that error, and, if necessary, create a new post.